# using semaphore in Perl

Tags: perl, fork, semaphore

this is a part of my code, which compiles some projects in parallel:

```
#main:#
our $sem = Thread::Semaphore->new();

for ($i = 0; $i < $cores_num-1; $i++)
{
    # Generating process
    local $curr_pid = fork ();
    # Child
    if ($curr_pid == 0)
    { 
        compiling_process($i,*REPORT);
        exit(0);
    }
    # Parent
    elsif (abs($curr_pid) > 10)
    {
        sleep (1);
        $running_processes++;   
    }
    # Error
    else
    {
        print "Error while forking!! \n";
        exit (0);
    }
}

# parent process:
compiling_process($i,*REPORT);
# Wait:
while ($running_processes > 0)
{
    $kid = 0;
    $kid = waitpid(-1,WNOHANG);
    if (abs($kid) > 10)
    {
        $running_processes--;
    }
    sleep (1);
}




sub compiling_process{
local $id = $_[0];
*REPORT = $_[1];
# Run until all targets are built:

while (1)   
{
$sem->down();   
##critical section
$sem->up();
}
```

}

This code is for compiling in parallel.
while running this code- sometimes I see 2 cores inside of the critical section at the same time! (the code works fine and all the projects are being built, but I must solve this problem..it causes a wast of time + wrong prints ) 
I am kind of desperate because I don't know what am I doing wrong.
is it wrong using semaphore in a function? ("sub compiling_proces")

any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the semaphore doesn't seem to work is because the child processes will maintain their own copies of `$sem` once they are `fork`-ed.

The `our` keyword gives `$sem` package-scope; it doesn't mean that the variable is shared across processes.

Probably the simplest fix is to use threads instead of an explicit fork to run the child processes:

```
use threads;
use Thread::Semaphore;

my $sem = Thread::Semaphore->new;

my @threads;

for my $i ( 0 .. $num_cores-1 ) {

    my $thr = threads->new( \&compiling_process, $i, *REPORT ); # Launch
    push @threads, $thr;
}

$_->join for @threads;                                          # Wait
```

See [`perldoc perlthrtut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlthrtut.html) for more details and examples.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try out your suggestion.